# dart angular vs debugging

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, angular-dart

I just got started with dart and I have managed to configure correctly dart command line projects and a flutter app within vs code, and debugging works as expected, to attempt a cross platform project
However with dart angular, i cant get breakpoints to work, the docs in the dart seem to focus mostly in flutter however i cant breakpoint within just this specific type of dart project.
This is my current dart launch.json.

```
{ 
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Dart",
      "program": "web/main.dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using dart version 2.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

> however i cant breakpoint within just this specific type of dart project

Right now there is a race condition in non-Flutter web debugging, where the breakpoints are not set up before the app starts, so any breakpoints in startup code are missed.

There's an open issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/830 but as a workaround you could try inserting a delay (eg. `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1))` or calling the [debugger](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-developer/debugger.html) function at the top of your `main` function if you need to break in startup code).